# Docker Compose error but portainer and other working

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

I am really confuse,
My server was setup about 2 weeks ago, with still learning and work to do to have it complete.
The server got a power fail when accidently turned off the UPS.

After restart, some containes are running and others not. Mostly Plex was not running. Portainer wouldn't list it. So I tried to compose back, start dockerd, etc. etc. with no real luck.

I am running
Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Docker 20.10.02
docker-compose version 1.27.4, build 40524192
docker-py version: 4.3.1
CPython version: 3.7.7
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0l  10 Sep 2019
Portainer 1.24.1

I can connect to Portainer and Organizr, my first two service but homeassistant, plex, doesn't work.
In portainer, I 1 stack with 5 container running but primary is listed as "Down" and when I click on it I have a message : "Failure Unable to connect to the Docker endpoint"

just running the command "docker version" is slow and would return "Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running? "

It seems Docker and Dockerd service are running. I tried to stop and restart, reboot.

When I try to run compose again I get :

```
jn@turcotteserver:~$ docker-compose -f ~/docker/docker-compose.yml up
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 426, in _make_request
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 421, in _make_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1344, in getresponse
  File "http/client.py", line 306, in begin
  File "http/client.py", line 267, in _read_status
  File "socket.py", line 589, in readinto
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 727, in urlopen
  File "urllib3/util/retry.py", line 403, in increment
  File "urllib3/packages/six.py", line 734, in reraise
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 426, in _make_request
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 421, in _make_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1344, in getresponse
  File "http/client.py", line 306, in begin
  File "http/client.py", line 267, in _read_status
  File "socket.py", line 589, in readinto
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 205, in _retrieve_server_version
  File "docker/api/daemon.py", line 181, in version
  File "docker/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in inner
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 228, in _get
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 543, in get
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
  File "requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/docker-compose", line 3, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 67, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 123, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/command.py", line 69, in project_from_options
  File "compose/cli/command.py", line 132, in get_project
  File "compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 43, in get_client
  File "compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 170, in docker_client
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 188, in __init__
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 213, in _retrieve_server_version
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
[764006] Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

And this is what I have in my docker compose

```
version: "3.6"
services:
  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer
    container_name: portainer
    restart: always
    command: -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    ports:
      - "9100:9000"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ${USERDIR}/docker/portainer/data:/data
      - ${USERDIR}/docker/shared:/shared
    environment:
      - TZ=${TZ}

  organizr:
    container_name: organizr
    hostname: organizr
    restart: always
    image: organizr/organizr
    volumes:
      - ${USERDIR}/docker/organizr:/config
      - ${USERDIR}/docker/shared:/shared
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    environment:
      - fpm=true #true or false | using true will provide better performance
      - branch=v2-master #v2-master or #v2-develop
      - PUID=${PUID}
      - PGID=${PGID}
      - TZ=${TZ}
#  mariadb:
#    image: "linuxserver/mariadb"
#    container_name: "mariadb"
#    hostname: mariadb
#    volumes:
#        - ${USERDIR}/docker/mariadb:/config
#    ports:
#      - target: 3306
#        published: 3306
#        protocol: tcp
#        mode: host
#    restart: always
#    environment:
#      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
#      - PUID=${PUID}
#      - PGID=${PGID}
#      - TZ=${TZ}


#  phpmyadmin:
#    hostname: phpmyadmin
#    container_name: phpmyadmin
#    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
#    restart: always
#    links:
#      - mariadb:db
#    ports:
#      - 8080:80
#    environment:
#      - PMA_HOST=mariadb
#      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}

#  watchtower:
#    container_name: watchtower
#    restart: always
#    image: v2tec/watchtower
#    volumes:
#      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
#    command: --schedule "0 0 4 * * *" --cleanup

  homeassistant:
    container_name: homeassistant
    restart: always
    image: homeassistant/home-assistant
    devices:
      - /dev/ttyUSB0:/dev/ttyUSB0
      - /dev/ttyUSB1:/dev/ttyUSB1
      - /dev/ttyACM0:/dev/ttyACM0
    volumes:
      - ${USERDIR}/docker/homeassistant:/config
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - ${USERDIR}/docker/shared:/shared
    ports:
      - "9091:8123"
    privileged: true
    environment:
      - PUID=${PUID}
      - TZ=${TZ}

  plexms:
    container_name: plexms
    restart: always
    network_mode: host
    image: plexinc/pms-docker
    volumes:
      - ${USERDIR}/docker/plexms:/config
      - /media/SSD860/Downloads/plex_tmp:/transcode
      - /media/hdd1/Media:/media/media1
      - /media/hdd2/Media:/media/media2
      - ${USERDIR}/docker/shared:/shared
    ports:
      - "32400:32400/tcp"
      - "3005:3005/tcp"
      - "8324:8324/tcp"
      - "32469:32469/tcp"
      - "1900:1900/udp"
      - "32410:32410/udp"
      - "32412:32412/udp"
      - "32413:32413/udp"
      - "32414:32414/udp"
    environment:
      - TZ=${TZ}
      - HOSTNAME="Turcotte Plex Server"
      - PLEX_CLAIM="claim-b_6kMsxaERgzacA9w-6R"
      - PLEX_UID=${PUID}
      - PLEX_GID=${PGID}
      - ADVERTISE_IP="http://192.168.3.112:32400/"

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    container_name: grafana
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - monitoring
    volumes:
      - grafana-volume:/vol01/Docker/monitoring

  influxdb:
    image: influxdb
    container_name: influxdb
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8086:8086"
    networks:
      - monitoring
    volumes:
      - influxdb-volume:/vol01/Docker/monitoring
    environment:
      - INFLUXDB_DB=telegraf
      - INFLUXDB_USER=telegraf
      - INFLUXDB_ADMIN_ENABLED=true
      - INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER=admin
      - INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD=Welcome123

  telegraf:
    image: telegraf
    container_name: telegraf
    restart: always
    extra_hosts:
      - “influxdb:192.168.3.112”
    environment:
      HOST_PROC: /rootfs/proc
      HOST_SYS: /rootfs/sys
      HOST_ETC: /rootfs/etc
    volumes:
      - ./telegraf.conf:/etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - /sys:/rootfs/sys:ro
      - /proc:/rootfs/proc:ro
      - /etc:/rootfs/etc:ro
#  broker:
#    image: eclipse-mosquitto
#    volumes:
#      - "./mosquitto:/mosquitto"
#    networks:
#      - localnet
#    ports:
#      - "1883:1883"
#  node-red:
#    image: nodered/node-red:latest
#    environment:
#      - TZ=Europe/Amsterdam
#    ports:
#      - "1880:1880"
#    networks:
#      - node-red-net
#    volumes:
#      - node-red-data:/data

networks:
  monitoring:
  localnet:
#  node-red-net:

volumes:
#  node-red-data:
  grafana-volume:
    external: true
  influxdb-volume:
    external: true
```

Any help would be helpful before I just scrap everything.
I am really thinking that docker and docker compose is too complicated. Even with an engineer degree and a computer science degree (20 years ago things were easier I think lol)